# Pivoting 2 columns from 3 Tables and creating pivot-column-names to avoid conflict - SQL-Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

#### Intro and Problem

In my example i have teachers, students and courses.I would like to have an overview which course is teached by whom in which rooms and all the studends in this course. I have the basic setup runnig (with some handcoded statements). But until now i had no luck to prepare the correct STUFF statement:

- Prepare `@colsStudents` so that i can put the name in the column header and remove the need to mess with the ids (adding 100) to avoid a conflict between rooms.id and students.id
- Prepare `@colsRooms` so that i do not have to hardocde the roomnames
- Putting i all together by using  `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`

You can find all sql-statements to create this schema and the data at the end.

[image: Table Diagramm]

#### Wanted Result Overview Courses,

I would like pivot the columns `RoomName` and `StudentName` and use the column values as the new column names. All SQL-Statements to create tables and data are at the end.

```
Id | Course | Teacher | A3 | E7 | Penny | Cooper | Koothrap. | Amy
---+--------+---------+----+----+-------+--------+-----------+-----+
1  | C# 1   | Marc G. |    | 1  |  1    |        |           |
2  | C# 2   | Sam S.  |    | 1  |  1    |        |      1    |
3  | C# 3   | John S. | 1  |    |       |    1   |           |
4  | C# 3   | Reed C. |    | 1  |       |        |      1    |
5  | SQL 1  | Marc G. | 1  |    |       |        |           |  
6  | SQL 2  | Marc G. | 1  |    |       |        |           |  
7  | SQL 3  | Marc G. |    | 1  |       |    1   |           |  1
8  | SQL 3  | Gbn     | 1  |    |       |        |      1    |
```

#### What i have so far

```
With PivotData as (
Select cd.Id, c.CourseName as Course, t.TeacherName as Teacher
        ,r.Id as RoomId, r.RoomName as RoomName
        ,100 + s.Id as StudentId, s.StudentName as Student 
    FROM CourseDetails cd 
        Left JOIN Courses c ON cd.CourseId = c.Id
        Left JOIN Teachers t ON cd.TeacherId = t.Id
        Left JOIN CourseMember cm ON cd.Id = cm.CourseDetailsId
        Left JOIN Students s ON cm.StudentId = s.Id 
        Left JOIN Rooms r ON cd.RoomId = r.Id
        )    
Select Course, Teacher
    , [1] as A3, [2] as E7 -- RoomColumns
    , [101] as Koothrappali, [102] as Cooper, [103] as Penny, [104] as Amy -- StudentColumns
    FROM (
        Select Course, Teacher, RoomName, RoomId,Student, StudentId
        From PivotData) src
    PIVOT( Max(RoomName) FOR RoomId IN ([1],[2])) as P1
    PIVOT( Count(Student) FOR StudentId IN ([101],[102],[103],[104]) ) as P2
```

[image: Pivot Result]

### What is missing

The above statement is prepared by hand. Since i do not know the Rooms or Students in advance i need to create the Pivot Statement for the Columns  Rooms and Students dynamically. On SO are plenty of examples how to do it. The normal way to do that is to use STUFF:

```
DECLARE @colsStudents AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @colsStudents = STUFF(
        (SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()] FROM 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 100 + Id AS y FROM dbo.Students) AS Y 
                ORDER BY y
                FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1
        ,1
        ,N'');
Select @colsStudents
```

This returns `[101],[102],[103],[104]` for the Student Ids. I added 100 to each id to avoid conflicts between the students.id and teh rooms.id column.

As mentioned in the intro i need to dynamically create something like this

```
[1] as RoomName_1, [2] as RoomName_1 -- RoomColumns
[1] as StudentName1, [2] as StudentName2, ... ,[4] as Amy -- StudentColumns
```

But all my tries with the stuff statement failed.

#### All SQL Statements to create the tables and data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Teachers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TeacherName] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Teachers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Students PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseName] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Courses PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoomName] [nchar](120) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Rooms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseDetails](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [CourseId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TeacherId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [RoomId] [int] NOT NULL,  
  CONSTRAINT PK_CourseDetails PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CourseDetails_Teachers_Id FOREIGN Key (TeacherId)
    REFERENCES dbo.Teachers (Id),   
  CONSTRAINT FK_CourseDetails_Courses_Id FOREIGN Key (CourseId)
    REFERENCES dbo.Courses (Id),    
  CONSTRAINT FK_CourseDetails_Rooms_Id FOREIGN Key (RoomId)
    REFERENCES dbo.Rooms (Id)       
)       


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseMember](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [CourseDetailsId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [StudentId] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_CourseMember PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CourseMember_CourseDetails_Id FOREIGN Key (CourseDetailsId)
    REFERENCES dbo.CourseDetails (Id),   
  CONSTRAINT FK_CourseMember_Students_Id FOREIGN Key (StudentId)
    REFERENCES dbo.Students (Id)     
)



INSERT INTO dbo.Courses (CourseName)
VALUES ('SQL 1 - Basics'),
    ('SQL 2 - Intermediate'),
    ('SQL 3 - Advanced'),   
    ('C# 1 - Basics'),
    ('C# 2 - Intermediate'),    
    ('C# 3 - Advanced')     

INSERT INTO dbo.Students (StudentName)
VALUES
   ('Koothrappali'),   
   ('Cooper'),
   ('Penny'),   
   ('Amy') 

INSERT INTO dbo.Teachers (TeacherName)
VALUES
   ('gbn '),
   ('Sam S.'),
   ('Marc G.'),   
   ('Reed C.'),
   ('John S.')

INSERT INTO dbo.Rooms (RoomName)
VALUES ('A3'), ('E7')


INSERT [dbo].[CourseDetails] (CourseId, TeacherId, RoomId) 
    VALUES (4, 3, 2),(5, 2, 2),
        (6, 5, 1),(6, 4, 2),
        (1,3,1),(2,3,1),(3,3,2),
        (3,1,1)

INSERT [dbo].[CourseMember] (CourseDetailsId, StudentId) 
    VALUES (1,3),(2,3),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1),(7,2),(7,4),(8,1)
```

Comment: Do you need the second aggregate to be a count?  Or do you just want a flag that the student is in the class?  Can a student actually be in the class more than once?

Comment: Currently the count is not needed; a flag would be enough. Out of my head i have no constraints that would prevent that a student is more than once in a course. But it is not likely that this is the case.

Comment: I found one reason why i have problems with stuff. The StudentName, TeacherName and RoomName was of type nchar(120) and therefore 120 signs are added into each field. I changed it to nvarchar(120).

Comment: Others may look at [dynamic pivot query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) or [pivot multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241450/sql-pivot-with-multiple-columns?rq=1) or this one [multiple column pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947281/multiple-column-pivot-in-t-sql?lq=1) or this one [pivot multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590799/tsql-pivot-multiple-columns?lq=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally would do this a bit different. Since you are trying to pivot two separate columns that screams to use the `UNPIVOT` function.

The unpivot will convert your multiple columns into rows to then pivot.

Since you have SQL Server 2008, you can use `CROSS APPLY` and values:

```
  select id, course, teacher, col, flag
  from
  (
    Select cd.Id, c.CourseName as Course, t.TeacherName as Teacher
      ,cast(r.Id as varchar(10))as RoomId
      , r.RoomName as RoomName
      ,cast(100 + s.Id as varchar(10)) as StudentId
      , s.StudentName as Student
      , '1' flag
    FROM CourseDetails cd 
    Left JOIN Courses c 
      ON cd.CourseId = c.Id
    Left JOIN Teachers t 
      ON cd.TeacherId = t.Id
    Left JOIN CourseMember cm 
      ON cd.Id = cm.CourseDetailsId
    Left JOIN Students s 
      ON cm.StudentId = s.Id 
    Left JOIN Rooms r 
      ON cd.RoomId = r.Id
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    values ('roomname', roomname),('student',student)
  ) c (value, col)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95a2/63). The unpivot generates a result similar to this:

```
| ID |               COURSE | TEACHER |          COL | FLAG |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |        C# 1 - Basics | Marc G. |           E7 |    1 |
|  1 |        C# 1 - Basics | Marc G. |        Penny |    1 |
|  2 |  C# 2 - Intermediate |  Sam S. |           E7 |    1 |
|  2 |  C# 2 - Intermediate |  Sam S. |        Penny |    1 |
|  2 |  C# 2 - Intermediate |  Sam S. |           E7 |    1 |
|  2 |  C# 2 - Intermediate |  Sam S. | Koothrappali |    1 |
|  3 |      C# 3 - Advanced | John S. |           A3 |    1 |
|  3 |      C# 3 - Advanced | John S. |       Cooper |    1 |
```

You will see that the `col` data contains all the values that you want to pivot. Once the data is in the rows, if will be easy to apply one pivot:

```
select id, course, teacher, 
  coalesce(A3, '') A3, 
  coalesce(E7, '') E7, 
  coalesce(Koothrappali, '') Koothrappali, 
  coalesce(Cooper, '') Cooper, 
  coalesce(Penny, '') Penny, 
  coalesce(Amy, '') Amy
from
(
  select id, course, teacher, col, flag
  from
  (
    Select cd.Id, c.CourseName as Course, t.TeacherName as Teacher
      ,cast(r.Id as varchar(10))as RoomId
      , r.RoomName as RoomName
      ,cast(100 + s.Id as varchar(10)) as StudentId
      , s.StudentName as Student
      , '1' flag
    FROM CourseDetails cd 
    Left JOIN Courses c 
      ON cd.CourseId = c.Id
    Left JOIN Teachers t 
      ON cd.TeacherId = t.Id
    Left JOIN CourseMember cm 
      ON cd.Id = cm.CourseDetailsId
    Left JOIN Students s 
      ON cm.StudentId = s.Id 
    Left JOIN Rooms r 
      ON cd.RoomId = r.Id
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    values ('roomname', roomname),('student',student)
  ) c (value, col)
) d
pivot
(
  max(flag)
  for col in (A3, E7, Koothrappali, Cooper, Penny, Amy)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95a2/44).

Then to convert this to dynamic SQL, you are only pivoting one column, so you will use the following to get the list of columns:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(col) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select id, roomname col, 1 SortOrder
                      from rooms
                      union all
                      select id, StudentName, 2
                      from Students
                    ) d
                    group by id, col, sortorder
                    order by sortorder, id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

This will get the list of distinct rooms and students that are then used in the pivot. So the final code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(col) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select id, roomname col, 1 SortOrder
                      from rooms
                      union all
                      select id, StudentName, 2
                      from Students
                    ) d
                    group by id, col, sortorder
                    order by sortorder, id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT  ', coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(col)+', '''') as '+QUOTENAME(col)
                    from 
                    (
                      select id, roomname col, 1 SortOrder
                      from rooms
                      union all
                      select id, StudentName, 2
                      from Students
                    ) d
                    group by id, col, sortorder
                    order by sortorder, id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'SELECT 
      id, course, teacher,' + @colsNull + ' 
     from
    (
      select id, course, teacher, col, flag
      from
      (
        Select cd.Id, c.CourseName as Course, t.TeacherName as Teacher
          ,cast(r.Id as varchar(10))as RoomId
          , r.RoomName as RoomName
          ,cast(100 + s.Id as varchar(10)) as StudentId
          , s.StudentName as Student
          , ''1'' flag
        FROM CourseDetails cd 
        Left JOIN Courses c 
          ON cd.CourseId = c.Id
        Left JOIN Teachers t 
          ON cd.TeacherId = t.Id
        Left JOIN CourseMember cm 
          ON cd.Id = cm.CourseDetailsId
        Left JOIN Students s 
          ON cm.StudentId = s.Id 
        Left JOIN Rooms r 
          ON cd.RoomId = r.Id
      ) d
      cross apply
      (
        values (''roomname'', roomname),(''student'',student)
      ) c (value, col)
    ) d
    pivot
    (
      max(flag)
      for col in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95a2/62).

Note I implemented a flag to be used in the pivot, this basically generates a Y/N if there is a value for the room or student.

This gives a final result:

```
| ID |               COURSE | TEACHER | A3 | E7 | KOOTHRAPPALI | COOPER | PENNY | AMY |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |        C# 1 - Basics | Marc G. |    |  1 |              |        |     1 |     |
|  2 |  C# 2 - Intermediate |  Sam S. |    |  1 |            1 |        |     1 |     |
|  3 |      C# 3 - Advanced | John S. |  1 |    |              |      1 |       |     |
|  4 |      C# 3 - Advanced | Reed C. |    |  1 |            1 |        |       |     |
|  5 |       SQL 1 - Basics | Marc G. |  1 |    |              |        |       |     |
|  6 | SQL 2 - Intermediate | Marc G. |  1 |    |              |        |       |     |
|  7 |     SQL 3 - Advanced | Marc G. |    |  1 |              |      1 |       |   1 |
|  8 |     SQL 3 - Advanced |    gbn  |  1 |    |            1 |        |       |     |
```

As a side note, this data can also be unpivoted using the `unpivot` function in sql server. (See [Demo with unpivot](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95a2/89))

Comment: AFAICT this looks promissing; i am still working on figuring it all out. Do you know if there are performance penalties / benefits to unpivot and then cross apply and pivot with just one column?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree The `CROSS APPLY` and `UNPIVOT` are doing the same thing, see a demo with unpivot -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95a2/89

Comment: I did a quick preliminary poor mans performance comparison:
`Declare at_sttime  datetime` and `Set at_sttime=getdate()` add your sql here `SELECT RTRIM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MS, at_sttime, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(10))) AS 'TimeTaken'`

In the first cold run my solution took 10ms, yours 43ms, 2nd run yours 50ms, mine 0ms (probably still in cache).
Since i had other processes running (videoplayback) and the cache was not emptied this is only a weak indicator. I am going to compare both solutions on a bigger sample data (40.000 rows). But this will take time to prepare.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Hmm, that is unusual. I have never had any performance issues with using pivot/unpivot

Answer (score 1):

You can create alias string for both pivot columns using dynamic sql query,
For example, for student columns :

```
DECLARE @colsStudents AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@colsstudentalias AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@colsRooms AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@colsRoomsalias AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @colsStudents = STUFF
(
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(100 + Id)
    FROM dbo.Students
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, ''
)


SELECT @colsstudentalias = STUFF
(
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(100 + Id) 
                + ' as ' + QUOTENAME(ltrim(rtrim(StudentName)))
    FROM dbo.Students
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, ''
)

SELECT @colsRooms = STUFF
(
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Id)
    FROM dbo.Rooms
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, ''
)


SELECT @colsRoomsalias = STUFF
(
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Id) 
                + ' as ' + QUOTENAME(ltrim(rtrim(RoomName)))
    FROM dbo.Rooms
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, ''
)

--SELECT @colsStudents, @colsstudentalias, @colsRooms, @colsRoomsalias

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = ';With PivotData as (
Select cd.Id, c.CourseName as Course, t.TeacherName as Teacher
        ,r.Id as RoomId, r.RoomName as RoomName
        ,100 + s.Id as StudentId, s.StudentName as Student 
    FROM CourseDetails cd 
        Left JOIN Courses c ON cd.CourseId = c.Id
        Left JOIN Teachers t ON cd.TeacherId = t.Id
        Left JOIN CourseMember cm ON cd.Id = cm.CourseDetailsId
        Left JOIN Students s ON cm.StudentId = s.Id 
        Left JOIN Rooms r ON cd.RoomId = r.Id
        )    
Select Course, Teacher
    , ' + @colsRoomsalias + '
    , ' + @colsstudentalias + '
    FROM (
        Select Course, Teacher, RoomName, RoomId,Student, StudentId
        From PivotData) src
    PIVOT( Max(RoomName) FOR RoomId IN (' + @colsRooms + ')) as P1
    PIVOT( Count(Student) FOR StudentId IN (' + @colsStudents + ') ) as P2'

exec (@sql)
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95a2/84)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a deeper look at both answers above and compare them with the one below.

- My problem was in filling the local variables @RoomNames and @StudentNames with the `Stuff()` Function.   One reason was that i had choosen the datatype `nchar(120)` instead of
  `nvarchar(120)` for the columns `StudentName`, `RoomName`.
- Another problem i had was that the new columnNames (Student instead of StudentName) where not recognized; therefore i replaced them with `*` in this statement: `Select * From (' + @PivotSrc + N') src`

[Philip Kelley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822004/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server?rq=1#7822414) suggested to use `SELECT @RoomIds = isnull(@RoomIds + ',', '') + '[' + Cast(Id as nvarchar(20))+ ']' FROM Rooms` instead of `STUFF()`  and since i find it shorter and easier to read  i am using it now.

#### Working Solution

```
DECLARE @StudentNames NVARCHAR(2000),    
    @RoomIds NVARCHAR(2000),
    @RoomNames NVARCHAR(2000),
    @PivotSrc NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @PivotBase NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @StudentNames = isnull(@StudentNames + ',', '') + '[' + StudentName + ']' FROM Students
SELECT @RoomIds = isnull(@RoomIds + ',', '') + '[' + Cast(Id as nvarchar(20))+ ']' FROM Rooms
SELECT @RoomNames = isnull(@RoomNames + ',', '') + '[' + RoomName + ']' FROM Rooms

SET @PivotSrc = N'Select cd.Id, c.CourseName as Course, t.TeacherName as Teacher
        ,r.Id as RoomId, r.RoomName as RoomName
        ,100 + s.Id as StudentId, s.StudentName as Student 
    FROM CourseDetails cd 
        Left JOIN Courses c ON cd.CourseId = c.Id
        Left JOIN Teachers t ON cd.TeacherId = t.Id
        Left JOIN CourseMember cm ON cd.Id = cm.CourseDetailsId
        Left JOIN Students s ON cm.StudentId = s.Id 
        Left JOIN Rooms r ON cd.RoomId = r.Id'

SET @PivotBase = N' Select Course, Teacher, ' 
        + @RoomNames + N', ' 
    + @StudentNames + N' FROM (
       Select * From (' + @PivotSrc + N') src
       PIVOT( Max(RoomName) FOR RoomName IN ('+@RoomNames+ N')) as P1
           PIVOT( Count(Student) FOR Student IN ('+@StudentNames+N') ) as P2) as T'

execute(@PivotBase)
```

Comment: What was your reason for using `nchar` instead of `varchar` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: Copy and Paste mistake that i did not notice for way to long.