# TSQL PIVOT MULTIPLE COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following table but unsure of whether it is possible to pivot this and retain all the labels.

```
RATIO               RESULT   SCORE   GRADE
Current Ratio       1.294    60      Good
Gearing Ratio       0.3384   70      Good
Performance Ratio   0.0427   50      Satisfactory
TOTAL               NULL     180     Good
```

I will admit to not being very good with the use of pivots, so after several attempts resulting in this output:

```
SELECT 'RESULT' AS 'Ratio'
  ,[Current Ratio] AS 'Current Ratio'
  ,[Gearing Ratio] AS 'Gearing Ratio'
  ,[Performance Ratio] AS 'Performance Ratio'
  ,[TOTAL] AS 'TOTAL'
FROM
(
  SELECT RATIO, RESULT 
  FROM GRAND_TOTALS
) AS SREC
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(RESULT) 
  FOR RATIO IN ([Current Ratio],[Gearing Ratio], [Performance Ratio], [TOTAL])
) AS PVT
```

This gives the result:

```
Ratio    Current Ratio   Gearing Ratio   Performance Ratio
Result   1.294           0.3384          0.0427
```

I will admit to be feeling very stumped on what to do next to produce the result I need which is:

```
Ratio    Current Ratio   Gearing Ratio   Performance Ratio   TOTAL
Result   1.294           0.3384          0.0427              NULL
Score    60              70              50                  180
Grade    Good            Good            Satisfactory        Good
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Column Pivot in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947281/multiple-column-pivot-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since you want to pivot multiple columns of data, I would first suggest unpivoting the `result`, `score` and `grade` columns so you don't have multiple columns but you will have multiple rows.

Depending on your version of SQL Server you can use the UNPIVOT function or CROSS APPLY.  The syntax to unpivot the data will be similar to:

```
select ratio, col, value
from GRAND_TOTALS
cross apply
(
  select 'result', cast(result as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'score', cast(score as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'grade', grade
) c(col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db4e8/3).  Once the data has been unpivoted, then you can apply the PIVOT function:

```
select ratio = col,
  [current ratio], [gearing ratio], [performance ratio], total
from
(
  select ratio, col, value
  from GRAND_TOTALS
  cross apply
  (
    select 'result', cast(result as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'score', cast(score as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'grade', grade
  ) c(col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for ratio in ([current ratio], [gearing ratio], [performance ratio], total)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db4e8/4). This will give you the result:

```
|  RATIO | CURRENT RATIO | GEARING RATIO | PERFORMANCE RATIO |     TOTAL |
|--------|---------------|---------------|-------------------|-----------|
|  grade |          Good |          Good |      Satisfactory |      Good |
| result |       1.29400 |       0.33840 |           0.04270 |    (null) |
|  score |      60.00000 |      70.00000 |          50.00000 | 180.00000 |
```

Comment: i'll allways be impressed by PIVOT solutions of true experts! I found this here: http://pratchev.blogspot.de/2009/01/pivoting-on-multiple-columns.html . In the second pragraph the author suggests two PIVOT clauses in one statement. is there a downside to this?

Comment: @DerU It really depends, I personally prefer to unpivot so the data is in an easier format then applying two pivots.

Comment: @DerU - I'm an huge fan of the approach in the article you have attached. I'm also in the same boat Taryn in that it does depend. I'll always run a "set statistics and time" and if anything looks untoward try another approach

Comment: @DerU So cool of you for sharing that link! It is useful!