# T-SQL Tricky grouping when creating dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql, join

I creating dynamic sql using multiple CTEs and temp tables. One of table looks like folloing:

```
id   datapoint_no load_timestamp practice
----------------- -------------- --------
1    1            2013-12-04     CSS
2    1            2013-12-04     TS
3    1            2013-12-04     MC
4    2            2013-11-25     CSS
5    2            2013-11-25     TS
6    2            2013-11-25     MC
7    3            2013-11-18     CSS
8    3            2013-11-18     TS
9    3            2013-11-18     MC
10   4            NULL           CSS
11   4            NULL           TS
12   4            NULL           MC
13   5            NULL           CSS
14   5            NULL           TS
15   5            NULL           MC
```

Also I have couple of CTEs which creates script with another cte =) based on table above like:

```
data_1 AS (
SELECT amount AS TCV,
    SUM(amount * probability/100) AS WeightedTCV,
    SUM(abr) AS ABR,
    SUM(abr * project_margin_c/100) AS ABP,
    SUM(NULL) AS ClosedDeals
FROM  dbo.opportunities
WHERE load_timestamp='2013-12-04' AND practice_c='CSS'
),
data_2 AS (
SELECT amount AS TCV,
    SUM(amount * probability/100) AS WeightedTCV,
    SUM(abr) AS ABR,
    SUM(abr * project_margin_c/100) AS ABP,
    SUM(NULL) AS ClosedDeals
FROM  dbo.opportunities
WHERE load_timestamp='2013-12-04' AND practice_c='TS'
),
..... about 15 other data_XXX
```

Now I want to complete this script with `select` and `from` and here I've been stopped. I need to union data which belong to same load_timestamp and left join all other data from from other timestamps).

Maybe I am using not the best way of initial script preparation but I do not know how to do it better way.

Finally something like following table should be result of script exection:

```
practice  load_timestamp_1  TCV_1 WeightedTCV_2 ABR_1 ABR_1 load_timestamp_2  TCV_2  WeightedTCV_2 ABR_2 ABR_2
CSS       2013-12-04        xxx   yyy           zzz   www   2013-11-25        xxx    yyy           zzz   www
TS        2013-12-04        xxx   yyy           zzz   www   2013-11-25        xxx    yyy           zzz   www
MC        2013-12-04        xxx   yyy           zzz   www   2013-11-25        xxx    yyy           zzz   www
...................
```

Comment: question about your final data grid: you have the "WeightedTCV_2" field in there twice. Is that by design? Or should the first one be "WeightedTCV_1"? Also wondering if you repeat these fields by design in the final data grid: "ABR_1", "ABR_1". Seems like based on your CTE, maybe that should be "ABR_1", "ABP_1"?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I have not understood your data structure correctly, please add some details to your question and I can revise. This is a variation of [TSQL PIVOT MULTIPLE COLUMNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590799/tsql-pivot-multiple-columns).

It is technically feasible to derive your field list in the PIVOT using dynamic SQL. [Click here for more details on that](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). But before implementing a solution that leverages dynamic SQL, [be sure you understand the risks](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Itzik Ben-Gan's example on how to build a dynamic PIVOT is excellent. I highly recommend his book: [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626022) and [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658145)

```
with MyTable
as
(
select 1 as id, 1 as datapoint_no,  '2013-12-04' as load_timestamp, 'CSS' as practice
union
select 2 as id, 1 as datapoint_no,  '2013-12-04' as load_timestamp, 'TS' as practice
union
select 3 as id, 1 as datapoint_no,  '2013-12-04' as load_timestamp, 'MC' as practice
union
select 4 as id, 2 as datapoint_no,  '2013-11-25' as load_timestamp, 'CSS' as practice
union
select 5 as id, 2 as datapoint_no,  '2013-11-25' as load_timestamp, 'TS' as practice
union
select 6 as id, 2 as datapoint_no,  '2013-11-25' as load_timestamp, 'MC' as practice
union
select 7 as id, 3 as datapoint_no,  '2013-11-18' as load_timestamp, 'CSS' as practice
union
select 8 as id, 3 as datapoint_no,  '2013-11-18' as load_timestamp, 'TS' as practice
union
select 9 as id, 3 as datapoint_no,  '2013-11-18' as load_timestamp, 'MC' as practice
),
opportunities
as
(
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-12-04' as load_timestamp, 'CSS' as practice_c
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-12-04' as load_timestamp, 'TS' as practice_c
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-12-04' as load_timestamp, 'MC' as practice_c   
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-11-25' as load_timestamp, 'CSS' as practice_c
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-11-25' as load_timestamp, 'TS' as practice_c
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-11-25' as load_timestamp, 'MC' as practice_c            
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-11-18' as load_timestamp, 'CSS' as practice_c
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-11-18' as load_timestamp, 'TS' as practice_c
union
select 123 as amount, .123 as probability, 456 as abr, .456 as project_margin_c
     , '2013-11-18' as load_timestamp, 'MC' as practice_c
), Step1
as
(
select t.practice
      ,t.load_timestamp
      ,t.datapoint_no
      ,sum(o.amount) as TCV
      ,sum(amount * probability/100) as WeightedTCV
      ,sum(abr) as ABR
      ,sum(abr * project_margin_c/100) as ABP
      ,0 AS ClosedDeals
  from MyTable t
  left join opportunities o
    on t.practice = o.practice_c
   and t.load_timestamp = o.load_timestamp
 group by t.practice
         ,t.load_timestamp
         ,t.datapoint_no
)
select practice, 
  [load_timestamp_1], [TCV_1], [WeightedTCV_1], [ABR_1], [ABP_1], [ClosedDeals_1],
  [load_timestamp_2], [TCV_2], [WeightedTCV_2], [ABR_2], [ABP_2], [ClosedDeals_2],
  [load_timestamp_3], [TCV_3], [WeightedTCV_3], [ABR_3], [ABP_3], [ClosedDeals_3]
from
(
select practice, col, value
  from Step1
  cross apply
  (
  select 'load_timestamp_' + cast(datapoint_no as varchar), load_timestamp union all
  select 'TCV_' + cast(datapoint_no as varchar), cast(TCV as varchar) union all
  select 'WeightedTCV_' + cast(datapoint_no as varchar), cast(WeightedTCV as varchar) union all
  select 'ABR_' + cast(datapoint_no as varchar), cast(ABR as varchar)  union all
  select 'ABP_' + cast(datapoint_no as varchar), cast(ABR as varchar)  union all
  select 'ClosedDeals_' + cast(datapoint_no as varchar), cast(ClosedDeals as varchar)
  ) c(col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([load_timestamp_1], [TCV_1], [WeightedTCV_1], [ABR_1], [ABP_1], [ClosedDeals_1],
  [load_timestamp_2], [TCV_2], [WeightedTCV_2], [ABR_2], [ABP_2], [ClosedDeals_2],
  [load_timestamp_3], [TCV_3], [WeightedTCV_3], [ABR_3], [ABP_3], [ClosedDeals_3])
) piv;
```