# Pivot on multiple columns (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have this set of data (list of actions), already cleaned and ready for the PIVOT operation.

[image]

How can I achieve something like this (aggregating the nº of actions; duration; gross value; net value... BY month)?

[image]

(preparing for the MS Certification and quite frustrated because I can't solve this using PIVOT)

Comment: Start with an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) so that people can concentrate on helping you instead of wasting time on boilerplate

Comment: You're allowed to use [multiple PIVOT expressions in a query](http://pratchev.blogspot.de/2009/01/pivoting-on-multiple-columns.html).  I believe you just have to make sure the results are going to be deterministic.  The other alternative is [UNPIVOTing to normalize the data into one column, and then PIVOTing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590799/tsql-pivot-multiple-columns).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to `unpivot` the data then you can `pivot` the result

Sample data

```
  create table piv(TimeRange varchar(50),Type varchar(50), Month int,ActionDuration int, GrossValue bigint, NetValue bigint)

  insert piv values
  ('09:00-10:00','Bonus'        ,1 ,30 ,0       ,0       ), 
  ('09:00-10:00','Bonus'        ,1 ,30 ,0       ,0       ),
  ('09:00-10:00','Billed'       ,1 ,30 ,77982   ,701838  ),
  ('09:00-10:00','Not Billed'   ,1 ,30 ,506124  ,4555116 ),
  ('10:00-11:00','Bonus'        ,1 ,30 ,0       ,0       ),
  ('10:00-11:00','Billed'       ,1 ,30 ,109739  ,987651  ),
  ('10:00-11:00','Billed'       ,1 ,30 ,109739  ,987651  ),
  ('10:00-11:00','Not Billed'   ,1 ,30 ,98021   ,882189  ),
  ('09:00-10:00','Bonus'        ,2 ,30 ,0       ,0       ),
  ('09:00-10:00','Billed'       ,2 ,30 ,288947  ,2600523 ),
  ('09:00-10:00','Billed'       ,2 ,30 ,288947  ,2600523 ),
  ('09:00-10:00','Not Billed'   ,2 ,30 ,64669   ,582021  ),
  ('10:00-11:00','Bonus'        ,2 ,30 ,0       ,0       ),
  ('10:00-11:00','Billed'       ,2 ,30 ,48738   ,438642  ),
  ('10:00-11:00','Not Billed'   ,2 ,30 ,269969  ,2429721 )
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TimeRange,
               TYPE,
               DATA,
               left(DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month , 0 ) - 1 ),3) + ' '
               + COLUMN_NAME AS PIV_COL
        FROM   Yourtable
               CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('ActionDuration',ActionDuration),
                                   ('GrossValue',GrossValue),
                                   ('NetValue',NetValue)) CS(COLUMN_NAME, DATA)) a
       PIVOT (sum(DATA)
             FOR PIV_COL IN([Jan ActionDuration],
                            [Jan GrossValue],
                            [Jan NetValue],
                            [Feb ActionDuration],
                            [Feb GrossValue],
                            [Feb NetValue])) PV
```

**Result**

```
TimeRange   TYPE        Jan ActionDuration  Jan GrossValue  Jan NetValue    Feb ActionDuration  Feb GrossValue  Feb NetValue
----------- ----------- ------------------  --------------  ------------    ------------------  --------------  -------------
09:00-10:00 Billed      30                  77982           701838          60                  577894              5201046
10:00-11:00 Billed      60                  219478          1975302         30                  48738               438642
09:00-10:00 Bonus       60                  0               0               30                  0                   0
10:00-11:00 Bonus       30                  0               0               30                  0                   0
09:00-10:00 Not Billed  30                  506124          4555116         30                  64669               582021
10:00-11:00 Not Billed  30                  98021           882189          30                  269969              2429721
```

Comment: Now I realize that the initial data was not "cleaned and ready" for the PIVOT operation. Thank you so much!