# SQL - error when using pivot command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am having trouble using the pivot command - I am getting the following error

> "Invalid column name '2013-03-22'. Invalid column name '2013-03-29'. Invalid column name '2013-04-05'.  Invalid column name 'Volume'. Invalid column name 'Week Ending Date'."

when running this code

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
   SELECT [Area], 
     [Region], 
     [Channel], 
     [Controller], 
     [2013-03-22] AS _dt1, 
     [2013-03-29] AS _dt2, 
     [2013-04-05] AS _dt3 
  FROM [DataTable]
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
   SUM ([Volume]) 
   FOR [Week Ending Date] IN ([2013-03-22], [2013-03-29], [2013-04-05])
) AS PivotTable
```

It seems to fit the correct format.. any ideas?

Comment: You've renamed your columns to `_dt1`, `_dt2`, etc in your subquery so the columns `[2013-03-22], [2013-03-29], [2013-04-05]` don't exist. You need to use the names of the aliases or skip the alias. Plus you have no column named `Volume`, or `Week Ending Date`.

Comment: @bluefeet: thanks, but isn't the idea to get rid of the volume and week columns through pivoting?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you want to sum it, but you don't have a `volume` column in your subquery.  If the column doesn't exist in the subquery it can't sum it.  What column in your subquery contains the volume value?  Can you create a SQL Fiddle with some sample data? Or even edit your question to include sample data?

Comment: thanks @bluefeet.. I can try this, but it seems more like a compilation error than a data error.. if I include [Volume] and [Week Ending Date] in the subquery, those errors go away, but I still get the error for the date columns...

Comment: Without seeing sample data and the final desired result, I'm guessing here but typically you pivot values that are in a single column - the subquery has your dates in separate columns which will prevent the pivot from working.  What exactly are you trying to do with the query? I've answered a lot of pivot questions and it's hard to see what you want as a final result without data. You might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15745076/426671) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19591362/426671) answer to help figure out the syntax.

Comment: thanks @bluefeet - I seem to have figured it out, see my response below.  Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that source table **should not** include the values for the columns to be pivoted, but **should** contain the columns containing the values to be pivoted and the values to be pivoted.  See below:

```
SELECT [Area], 
[Region], 
[Channel], 
[Controller],
[2013-03-22] as _dt1, 
[2013-03-29] as _dt2, 
[2013-04-05] as _dt3
FROM 
(
SELECT [Area], 
[Region], 
[Channel], 
[Controller], 
[Volume],
[Week Ending Date]
FROM [DataTable]
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT(SUM ([Volume]) FOR [Week Ending Date] IN ([2013-03-22], [2013-03-29], 
[2013-04-05])) 
AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

usually I do my pivot columns dynamically then I run execute sp_executesql @query

1. find the distinct DATEs '2013-03-22' ...  then turn it to string
   use STUFF and XML PATH
2. replace it in your embedded SQL query

so you never HARD CODE YOUR COLUMNS

here example I have

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
   select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  N',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
   FROM sys.tables AS t
   INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
   WHERE t.name = 'tagCloudLibrary'
    and c.name not in ('langID')
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')


    set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from tagCloudLibrary'
    execute sp_executesql @query;
```

HERE if your PIVOT is correct  do CORRECT WHERE CLAUSE for STUFF...

```
  DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
   select @cols = STUFF((SELECT top 10  N',' + QUOTENAME(LastActivityDate)  
   FROM DataTable   
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')

     select @cols

     set query = N'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT [Area], [Region], [Channel], [Controller], ' +  @cols 
     + N' FROM [DataTable]) AS SourceTable '
    + N' PIVOT  (SUM ([Volume]) FOR [Week Ending Date] IN (' +  @cols  + ') AS PivotTable '

     execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Obviously who downgrade my solution never in his life did programmatically PIVOTTING  and HARD CODE HIS COLUMNS