# Merge two columns into single row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Test data table - user_traveldetails

```
ID  FromDate ToDate   UserId

1  1/1/2014 1/10/2014  44

2  2/1/2014 3/10/2014  44

3  1/1/2015 2/10/2015  44
```

Expected Output:

```
FromDate1  ToDate1    FromDate2 ToDate2    FromDate3  ToDate3    UserId
1/1/2014   1/10/2014  2/1/2014  3/10/2014  1/1/2015   2/10/2015  44
```

I required fromdate and todate in to the single row.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);   
    SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT top 12 ',' + quotename(fromdate) FROM      User_TravelDetails group by(fromdate) order by MAX(fromdate) desc FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')     
        set @query = 'Select *  from (select id as fromid, email as fromemail, ' + @cols + '     from   (   SELECT *    FROM
       (select top 10000 A.ID,Email,userid,FromDate,visit from UserMaster A
        inner join User_TravelDetails B     
        on A.ID= B.USerid order by B.FromDate
        ) as s  PIVOT 
        ( MIN(FromDate) FOR [FromDate] IN (' + @cols + ')
        )AS pvt
        ) as X)     
     P join 

    (Select id as toid, email as toemail,' + @cols +
     'from(SELECT * FROM (select top 10000
     A.ID,Email,userid,toDate,visit from UserMaster A
     inner join
     User_TravelDetails B   on A.ID= B.USerid order by B.FromDate   ) as s
     PIVOT(MIN(toDate) FOR [toDate] IN (' + @cols + ')  )AS pvt2
     ) as Y ) Q on P.fromemail=Q.toemail'
     print @query   EXEC
     SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Please help on the query.
Thanks

Comment: Google : SQL-Server pivot .

Comment: Which field do I need to use in pivot FOR[Column_Name], Please advice.

Comment: FromDate and ToDate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590799/tsql-pivot-multiple-columns

Comment: is there a max no of rows per UserId ?

Comment: Yes I have to show max 12 details per user @sagi using fromdate and todate not working in my case Do I need to go with dynamic query or simple query?

Comment: @Raj Then post here the code that you've tried, and we'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @sagi Posted my query

Comment: That is just unreadable. Please put some effort in formatting that.

Comment: @trincot It is readable now..

Comment: Able to fix issue thanks everyone for response..