# UnPivot with Multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

i have [pivot] table as below.

```
A       B       C       D           E       F        G      H     I          J      K    L      M       N   O       P
400.71  2.23    26.71   64847.63    0       0        0      0     0          161    0   31.29   0       0   2018    January
761.4   4.23    50.76   56724.12    0       0        0      0     0          74     0   29.9    0       0   2018    February
535.81  2.98    35.72   48323.59    0       0        0      0     0          90     0   42.09   0       0   2018    March
490.47  2.72    32.7    76690.51    0.77    14.72    0.81   1.59  247.93     156    0   36.84   0       0   2018    April
461.8   2.57    30.79   53348.36    1.58    1.86     0.15   1.58  183.05     115    0   40.11   0       0   2018    May
528.3   2.94    35.22   79223.21    0       0        0      0     0          149    0   38.38   0       0   2018    June
447.8   2.49    29.85   69752.76    1.77    3.09     0.25   3     466.9      155    0   42.57   0.01    0   2018    July
488.72  2.76    33.1    87675.79    4.29    11.94    0.34   5.29  949.58     179    0   40.09   0.01    0   2018    August
374.28  2.08    24.95   80357.47    1.65    5.01     0.25   6.97  1496.05    214    0   45.62   0.02    0   2018    September
```

I want to get it arranged like the following:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591362/3266499)

Comment: @Mazhar yes I tried but no fulfilled my requirements.

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: @Mazhar if you have any idea please resolve my question because of don't have any idea about this.

Comment: @shael  you said you tried something but didn't fulfil your requirements. Post that code, maybe we can help with fixing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to unpivot and pivot.  I would do tis as:

```
select t.o, v.category,
       max(case when t.p = 'January' then v.val end) as jan,
       max(case when t.p = 'February' then v.val end) as feb,
       . . .
       max(case when t.p = 'December' then v.val end) as dec
from t cross apply
     (values ('a', a), ('b', b), . . . ('n', n)
     ) v(category, val)
group by t.o, t.p;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempData')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TempData
;WITH CTE(A      , B     ,  C     ,  D        ,   E     ,  F     ,   G    ,  H    , I      ,  J    ,  K  ,  L    , M    ,   N,  O   ,   P)
AS
(
SELECT 400.71 , 2.23  ,  26.71 ,  64847.63 ,   0     ,  0     ,   0    ,  0    , 0      ,  161  ,  0  , 31.29 , 0    ,   0,  2018,   'January'  UNION ALL
SELECT 761.4  , 4.23  ,  50.76 ,  56724.12 ,   0     ,  0     ,   0    ,  0    , 0      ,  74   ,  0  , 29.9  , 0    ,   0,  2018,   'February' UNION ALL
SELECT 535.81 , 2.98  ,  35.72 ,  48323.59 ,   0     ,  0     ,   0    ,  0    , 0      ,  90   ,  0  , 42.09 , 0    ,   0,  2018,   'March'    UNION ALL
SELECT 490.47 , 2.72  ,  32.7  ,  76690.51 ,   0.77  ,  14.72 ,   0.81 ,  1.59 , 247.93 ,  156  ,  0  , 36.84 , 0    ,   0,  2018,   'April'    UNION ALL
SELECT 461.8  , 2.57  ,  30.79 ,  53348.36 ,   1.58  ,  1.86  ,   0.15 ,  1.58 , 183.05 ,  115  ,  0  , 40.11 , 0    ,   0,  2018,   'May'      UNION ALL
SELECT 528.3  , 2.94  ,  35.22 ,  79223.21 ,   0     ,  0     ,   0    ,  0    , 0      ,  149  ,  0  , 38.38 , 0    ,   0,  2018,   'June'     UNION ALL
SELECT 447.8  , 2.49  ,  29.85 ,  69752.76 ,   1.77  ,  3.09  ,   0.25 ,  3    , 466.9  ,  155  ,  0  , 42.57 , 0.01 ,   0,  2018,   'July'     UNION ALL
SELECT 488.72 , 2.76  ,  33.1  ,  87675.79 ,   4.29  ,  11.94 ,   0.34 ,  5.29 , 949.58 ,  179  ,  0  , 40.09 , 0.01 ,   0,  2018,   'August'   UNION ALL
SELECT 374.28 , 2.08  ,  24.95 ,  80357.47 ,   1.65  ,  5.01  ,   0.25 ,  6.97 , 1496.05,  214  ,  0  , 45.62 , 0.02 ,   0,  2018,   'September'
)
SELECT * INTO TempData FROM CTE

SELECT [Year],Category, 
 ISNULL([January]  ,'0' ) AS [January]
,ISNULL([February] ,'0' ) AS [February]
,ISNULL([March]    ,'0' ) AS [March]
,ISNULL([April]    ,'0' ) AS [April]
,ISNULL([May]      ,'0' ) AS [May]
,ISNULL([June]     ,'0' ) AS [June]
,ISNULL([July]     ,'0' ) AS [July]
,ISNULL([August]   ,'0' ) AS [August]
,ISNULL([September],'0' ) AS [September]
,ISNULL([October]  ,'0' ) AS [October]
,ISNULL([November] ,'0' ) AS [November]
,ISNULL([December] ,'0' ) AS [December]

FROM
(
SELECT O AS [Year],P AS Months,data,Category 
FROM TempData
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(A ,'A' ),(B,'B'),(C,'C'), (D,'D'),(E,'E'),(F,'F'),(G,'G'),
                   (H,'H'),(I,'I'),(J,'J'),(K,'K'),(L,'L'),(M,'M'),(N,'N')
            )Dt (data,Category)
)dt2
PIVOT
(
MAX(data) FOR Months IN ([January]
                        ,[February]
                        ,[March]
                        ,[April]
                        ,[May]
                        ,[June]
                        ,[July]
                        ,[August]
                        ,[September]
                        ,[October]
                        ,[November]
                        ,[December]
                        )
)Pvt
```

Dynamic Sql Approach

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..##Months')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##Months

SELECT number,
        DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH ,number-DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS Months
        INTO ##Months
FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE type='P'
AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 12 ORDER BY 1

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) ,
        @Sql2 nvarchar(max) ,
        @Query nvarchar(max),
        @ISNUllQuery nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Query= STUFF((SELECT  ', '+QUOTENAME(Months)  FROM ##Months ORDER BY ##Months.number FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 
SELECT @ISNUllQuery =STUFF((SELECT  ', '+'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(Months)+',''0'') AS '+QUOTENAME(Months)
                            FROM ##Months ORDER BY ##Months.number FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 

SELECT DISTINCT @Sql2= 'SELECT [Year],Category,'+@ISNUllQuery+' 
                        FROM(
                        SELECT [O] AS [Year],[P] AS MonthInfo,CAST(Data AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Data,Category
                        FROM TempData CROSS APPLY (VALUES ' +STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ', '+'('+(COLUMN_NAME) +','+''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''+')'
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE TABLE_NAME='TempData' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('o','p')FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
                        + ' ) AS Dt (Data,Category) )dtb PIVOT(MAX(Data) FOR  MonthInfo IN ('+@Query+')) AS PVT'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TempData' 

PRINT @Sql2
EXEC (@Sql2)
```